# Granular role access on a per Entity basis

Tags: 8, entities

I have a config entity that I would like to grant access to on a role based level. There is going to be one role to access the entities, but how can I assign access on a *per* entity basis?

My naive thinking is to add a `$roles` array instance variable, and add each individual role to that, then create a custom `EntityAccessControlHandler` class, implementing `EntityAccessControlHandlerInterface` that checks the array for all of the users roles, but that doesn't seem like a very good solution.

Comment: Using your own access handler is a perfectly valid approach. Although if it is role-based why don't you use permissiona as usually?

Comment: Won't default behavior grant access to all entities, not just each instance of an entity? These are going to be used for authenticating to private directories and I can't have people accessing files that they don't have explicit permissions to view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but that doesn't seem like a very good solution.

Yes, it is.

What you're saying makes perfect sense, just do it :)

access() (or checkAccess()) is called for each entity separately, you can implement any imaginable logic in there, that's completely up to you.